# AWS S3 Files how to properly store images and image compressing

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, xamarin.forms

I am building a mobile app similar to Instagram in terms of working with Images. I am using amazon s3 to store the images and Mysql for the file path. I'm trying to ensure users upload great quality pictures but also ensure the file size is reasonable, Should I compress the images?  Does anyone have an idea and what is the acceptable size for an image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of "acceptable" is totally up to you!

You should certainly store a **high-quality image** (probably at the original resolution), but you would also want to have **smaller images for thumbnails and web/app viewing**. This will make it faster to serve images and will reduce bandwidth costs.

A common technique is to **have Amazon S3 trigger an AWS Lambda function** when a new image is uploaded. The Lambda function can then **resize the image into multiple sizes**. Later, when your app wishes to retrieve an image, it can point to a resized image rather than the original.

When resizing images, you can also consider **image quality**. This allows JPG files to reduce in size without needing to reduce in resolution.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your reply, I've added the thumbnail bucket, which has really drastically improved the app speed. Also, if you know. How do people generally store the files in the AWS buckets for an app similar to Instagram? For example, I rename the files to a Guid Id and store them directly into the bucket and the file name to MySQL database. Is that the best way to do it or is the something I could do the AWS bucket side?

Comment: That's a great way to do it. It avoids filename clashes and also improves security by making it hard (but not impossible!) to find the filenames.

Comment: Hi John me again :) you are practically helping me build this thing at this point. I wanted to know I'm searching around. I'm looking for the best place to host my Asp.net core API. I've used AWS RDS for my Database, but I can't see how I can do it for my API

Comment: @Java_Dude If you're seeking advice, the folks at https://www.reddit.com/r/aws are generally happy to interact and offer suggestions. There would be many who have built similar systems.